# Ormlite relation and inhertitance

Tags: inheritance, ormlite

I wonder if there is a chance to build a relation to interhited classes.
The example below does not work, because it throws the error that the relation "person" does not exist. If I place the DatabaseTable Tag above the Person Class it doesn work either.
Does Ormlite support a relation to inherited objects?

```java
public abstract class Person{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField
    public String name;
    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private School school;
 }

@DatabaseTable
 public class Student extends Person{
    @DatabaseField
    public String class;
    @DatabaseField
    public String year;
 }

 @DatabaseTable
 public class Teacher extends Person{
    @DatabaseField
    public String title;
 }

 @DatabaseTable
 public class School {
     @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
     public int id;
     @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true)
     ForeignCollection<Person> persons;
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

give http://code.google.com/p/compot/ a shot. It is still in beta, but it's focused on entity inheritance and is really easy to use.

Comment: Please mention you are affiliated to this project. It's quite ok to do self-promotion on SO, but that should be made clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response.

Unfortunately, this won't work.  The `School` class has to query 2 different tables to build the `persons` foreign collection field.

You could accomplish this with a `Person` table with the `Student` and `Teacher` having a foreign `Person` field, but [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has no way to do this for you automagically.

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Student {
    @DatabaseField
    public String class;
    @DatabaseField
    public String year;
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    public Person person;
}
```

Then `Person` would not be `abstract` and there would be a `Person` table.   That's probably how Hibernate does it under the covers.